A* algorithm is not returning an existent path as expected
The A* algorithm, implemented in Python, is not returning the expected path even when a valid path exists between the start and goal nodes. The algorithm is expected to find the shortest path between two points on a grid, but it is returning 'None' instead of the path. I chose Manhattan distance since the goal of this algorithm is to find a path between a fruit and snake in the Snake Game. I chose the g cost of neighbour to be updated according to the path, that's why it's current_node.g_cost  + 1
I'm new to search algorithms and programming in general so sorry for the spaghetti code!
Here's the code
import math
import heapq
from pygame import Vector2
class NODE:
    def __init__(self, position, g_cost, h_cost, parent, isObstacle):
        self.position = position
        self.g_cost = g_cost
        self.h_cost = h_cost
        self.parent = parent
        self.isObstacle = isObstacle

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.position == other.position

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.fCost() < other.fcost()

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.position)

    def fCost(self):
        return self.g_cost + self.h_cost

class ASTAR:
    def __init__(self):
        # just initializes the class
        pass

    def getNeighbours(self, node):
        neighbours = []

        for x in range(-1, 2):
            if x == 0:
                continue
            checkX = node.position[0] + x
            if checkX >= 0 and checkX < 16:
                neighbours.append(NODE((checkX, node.position[1]), node.g_cost + 1, float('inf'), node, False))

        for y in range(-1, 2):
            if y == 0:
                continue
            checkY = node.position[1] + y
            if checkY >= 0 and checkY < 16:
                neighbours.append(NODE((node.position[0], checkY), node.g_cost + 1, float('inf'), node, False))

        return neighbours
    def findManhattanDistance(self, node1, node2):
        x1, y1 = node1.position
        x2, y2 = node2.position
        return abs(x1 - x2) + abs(y1 - y2)
    def search(self, start_node, goal_node):
        OPEN = []
        CLOSED = set()
        start_node.h_cost = self.findManhattanDistance(start_node, goal_node)  # Calculate h_cost for start node
        goal_node.h_cost = 0  # Goal node's h_cost is 0
        heapq.heappush(OPEN, (start_node.fCost(), start_node))
        while OPEN:
            current_cost, current_node = heapq.heappop(OPEN)
            print(current_cost)
            print(current_node)
            CLOSED.add(current_node)

            if (current_node.position == goal_node.position):
                return self.retracePath(start_node, goal_node)


            for neighbour in self.getNeighbours(current_node):
                if neighbour.isObstacle == True or neighbour in CLOSED:
                    continue
                new_g_cost = current_node.g_cost + 1
                if new_g_cost < neighbour.g_cost:
                    neighbour.g_cost = new_g_cost
                    neighbour.h_cost = self.findManhattanDistance(neighbour, goal_node)
                    neighbour.parent = current_node

                    if neighbour not in OPEN:
                        heapq.heappush(OPEN, (neighbour.fCost(), neighbour))

        return None

    def retracePath(self, start_node, goal_node):
        path = []
        current_node = goal_node

        while (current_node != start_node):
            path.append(current_node)
            current_node = current_node.parent

        path.append(start_node)
        path.reverse()

        return path

astar = ASTAR()

start_node = NODE((0, 0), 0, 0, None, False)  # Start node
goal_node = NODE((8, 8), 0, 0, None, False)   # Goal node

print(astar.search(start_node, goal_node))


One thing that strikes me is the diffence in __lt__ and __eq__ behaviour of your node type. That's surely confusing. Further, document parameters and return values. Write one full sentence documenting what they mean. I don't know for example what search() returns. Also, take a look at PEP8, which is about coding style. Adopting a standard style helps you read others' code and others read your's. Lastly, use a debugger to step through the code. That should allow you to quickly find when the code takes the wrong turn.

Just to elaborate on the __lt__/__eq__ part: Normally, when a<b is false and b<a is false, i.e. neither is less than the other, then the two are equal. Your code doesn't implement this behaviour.

supposedly, the _lt returns a boolean that tells if the cost of a node is less than another and the eq if the position of a node is equal to another one. the search returns None if no path is found, and a path if it is found. The path is calculated using the retrace Path method. Regarding the PEP8, I had no idea that it existed. I'm sorry for my code I'll make sure to use the proper coding conventions from now on. btw sorry for my ignorance but what is a debugger?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZJnGOwzHtU -- if you're using an IDE, you will probably find better integrations and according video tutorials.

Thanks, I have done as you advised me, and discovered that the issue was due to some simple mistakes like the fact that the new_g_cost has to be less or equal than the current_node_g_cost instead of just lesser and also that the parent of the goal node has to be updated when it reaches it. It now works as intended!
